# Get file metadata after opening in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, nsfilemanager

I am opening files (as of now PDF only) in my app using the AppDelegate's

```
application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options.
```

How can I get the file's metadata such as title, authors, content creator? I am able to get data such as NSFileCreationDate, NSFileExtensionHidden and so on using

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[url path] error:&error];
```

Comment: Please paste the whole code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MTPDF`. Please find it at : https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTPDF

```
MTPDF *pdf = [MTPDF PDFWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@",pdf.title, pdf.version, pdf.author, pdf.creator, pdf.subject, pdf.creationDate, pdf.modifiedDate);
```

I have used it and it is very useful